# Put permissions/access rights to some individual

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a web app scheduler using Flask/Python but I hit a wall right away. I have plans on how to build the app but I just don't have the slightest idea on how to apply it.

So basically what I have in mind is that, one employee with some access or permission to a specific job (eg. frontend, backend, warehouse). Say this #1 employee can do front and back end but not warehouse then #2 employee can only do warehouse only.

I've tried using @classmethod but I don't think that's the right approach.

https://gist.github.com/decenttaro/6b3d80b96d56f1285565af41e6c7014c

Comment: What's your code trying to do? Your problem was clear from the question but what solution are you trying to implement?

Comment: @DroidX86 Well, I don't know how to link the Permission Class to some of the employees so I can't give you anything. So basically, Im stuck from what I have in the code right now.